# RactiveJS returning different results while running same code in different places

Tags: ractivejs

Yet again I'm facing another problem.. seems that looping an array into an attribute causes RactiveJS to act wierdly and show only the last item.

```
<div id="test">{{ # online }} {{{ friends[ this ]+'<br/>' }}} {{ else }} No friends online {{ / }}</div>
<div data-tooltip="{{ # online }} {{ friends[ this ]+' -- ' }} {{ else }} No friends online {{ / }}">- this guy overhere doesn't want to show the same text:</div>
<div data-tooltip="{{ # online:num }} {{ num+' ' }} {{ else }} No friends online {{ / }}">- on the other hand, showing indexes works fine, though i can't access the friends name:</div>
```

No matter how hard I try to fix it, it just behaves the same. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjpt1yus/2/).

Comment: Correction there. It only shows the first item, not the last. You can fix it by unshifting both values at the same time (.unshift(2,6)). My guess is that by some reason ractive doesn't re-render the "attribute-loop" the second time you unshift because it isn't done with the first re-render. Seems like a bug to me, but there might be something I don't see here.

Comment: There's an PR (https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/pull/1742) that I believe addresses this.